# Docker compose fails to create volume on OSX

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker-compose to create a volume on my MAC, and I ran into a weird behavior that I don't really understand where `docker-compose` fails to run because of a volume owning user regardless to the permissions set on the folder.

First, here is my docker file and docker-compose file:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian

RUN groupadd -r test && useradd -r -g test test

VOLUME /var/test
# RUN mkdir -p /var/test && chown -R test:test /var/test
RUN mkdir -p /var/test
COPY test.sh /var/test/test.sh

CMD ["sh", "/var/test/test.sh"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
    test:
      build: .
      volumes:
          - test:/var/test
volumes:
  test:
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: "/tmp/vols"
```

#### Structure:

```
|____tmp
| |____Dockerfile
| |____vols
| |____docker-compose.yml
```

#### Running docker compose:

```
➜  /tmp docker-compose up
Creating tmp_test_1 ... error

ERROR: for tmp_test_1  Cannot create container for service test: failed to chmod on /var/lib/docker/volumes/tmp_test/_data: chmod /var/lib/docker/volumes/tmp_test/_data: operation not permitted

ERROR: for test  Cannot create container for service test: failed to chmod on /var/lib/docker/volumes/tmp_test/_data: chmod /var/lib/docker/volumes/tmp_test/_data: operation not permitted
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

#### Permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx   2 root   wheel   64 May  3 12:20 vols
```

#### Solutions that worked for me:

1. Changing the owner of `/tmp/vols` from `root`, but I was wondering if there is something better
2. Creating any file in `/tmp/vols` seems to solve this, why????

Basically my question is: why does this happen, and how should I fix it?

I can't find an explanation in the docs for this, and I want to make sure I am not missing anything important.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running docker-compose as root ?

Comment: no, I thought I shouldn't do that...

Comment: Do you mean: it works if the owner of /tmp/vols is NOT root ?

Comment: exactly @Philippe :)
But also if you create any random file inside it

Comment: Why you created vols with root in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your workarounds. Faced with same problem, but on Ubuntu 20.04. Creating file inside empty volume directory helps. But still have no idea why :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, what we did is just change the file owner to not be `root`.
If anyone will have a better suggestion, I will accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I had a corrupted _data and _dbs in the folder where docker-compose.yml was located. deleted and recreated the _data and _dbs folders and the system was up and running.